# What is the purpose of reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and reading some code as follows:

```
template<typename T>
std::istream & read(std::istream* stream, T& value){
    return stream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}
```

and call it:

```
size_t size;
read(&stream, size);
```

Can anyone explain what is the purpose of reinterpret_cast used here and what is result after read function is invoked?

UPDATE:

The question is:

If the stream contains a string e.g "test", after read is invoked, value's type becomes char * and its content is "test"?

Comment: Google is your friend. Try `reinterpret_cast c++`, and look at the second and third results.

Comment: That code snippet appears to be an attempt to write a generic serialization routine. If that's in fact what's going on, the approach shown is quite naïve and dangerous.

Comment: @In silico If the stream contains a string e.g "test", after read is invoked, value's type becomes char * and its content is "test"?

Comment: @KenWhite the second and third google results may not be identical from user to user, region to region, or day to day.

Comment: @justin: Good point, but it doesn't change the fact that a basic search would answer this question.

Comment: @KenWhite oh, i agreed with the GIYF bit :)

Comment: @Foredoomed: Who knows? Whether the code snippet works depends critically on the compiler and/or the platform (the immediately obvious problem I see is the issue of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). It's not much use to talk about its behavior when `reinterpret_cast` is used in this manner.

Comment: @Foredoomed: A general rule with `reinterpret_cast`: if you don't know what it means, then you aren't ready you *use it*.

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast<T>()` forces a given bit-pattern to be interpreted as the type you desire. It is the most "brutal" among casts.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Allows any pointer to be converted into any other pointer type. Also allows any integral >type to be converted into any pointer type and vice versa.
>
> Misuse of the reinterpret_cast operator can easily be unsafe. Unless the desired >conversion is inherently low-level, you should use one of the other cast operators.
>   The reinterpret_cast operator can be used for conversions such as `char*` to `int*`, or >`One_class*` to `Unrelated_class*`, which are inherently unsafe.
>
> The result of a `reinterpret_cast` cannot safely be used for anything other than being >cast back to its original type. Other uses are, at best, nonportable.

---

In you example

```
template<typename T>
std::istream & read(std::istream* stream, T& value){
    return stream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}
```

it is used to read from a given stream and cast the read data to `char*` to treat it as a sequence of bytes (assuming `char` is unsigned by default).

Comment: Okay, done... Didn't know about the syntax. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` function simply reads a number of bytes into a buffer, and the `reinterpret_cast` here turns an arbitrary rvalue into such a buffer by overriding the actual type of the value. If the stream actually did contain a value of the correct type, the result is that this value is stored into `value`.

Comment: If the stream contains a string e.g "test", after read is invoked, value's type becomes char * and its content is "test"?

Comment: value does **not** change its type, but yes, if the type of value was `char[5]` when calling this function, and the stream contained the 5 bytes `’t’, ‘e’, ’s’, ’t’, ‘\0’`, then value would indeed contain “test” (strings are NOT a good application for this routine, because they are typically not fixed length, and if they are, one wouldn’t write a terminator).